# Is there a way to implement functionality same as underscore pick function in Java? If so , how?

Tags: java

Consider below code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<Person> items=new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Person(1,"hari","aa"));
        items.add(new Person(2,"das","bb"));
        items.add(new Person(3,"giri","cc"));
        System.out.println(items);
        };
     }


class Person{
    int num;
    String name;
    String dept;
    Person(int num,String name,String dept){
        this.num=num;
        this.name=name;
        this.dept=dept;
    }   
}
```

Then i need to construct an List from this with object which has only name and dept properties in List. Is there a way to implement the same?

For instance,
Existing array is of form:
[{num:1,name:"hari",dept:"aa"},{num:2,name:"das",dept:"bb"},{num:3,name:"giri",dept:"cc"}]

New array require to be like : 
[{name:"hari",dept:"aa"},{name:"das",dept:"bb"},{name:"giri",dept:"cc"}]

Comment: Sorry.List. Same as how existing arraylist.

Comment: What will be the type of each element in this `List`? As in `List<?>`. What to write instead of `?`

Comment: could you add it to your question what it is that should be the end result?

Comment: Objects with only name and dept properties. 
Existing now has num,name and dept .

Comment: As in `class PersonLite {String name; String dept}` ?

Comment: You can create a new Person function with only name and dept and can have num set to some default value, that way you can initialize a Person variable with just name and dept.

Comment: Looks like you want to create a JSON array. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a second constructor:

```
class Person{
    int num;
    String name;
    String dept;
    Person(int num,String name,String dept){
        this.num=num;
        this.name=name;
        this.dept=dept;
    }   
    Person(String name,String dept){
        this.name=name;
        this.dept=dept;
    }   
}
```

Note: the Person objects will still have the num property, but it will be set to the default value (`0`). If that's not what you want, perhaps use a base class Person with only name and dept, and a subclass IndexedPerson (or whatever you want to call it) with all three properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think your should use Java stream to trasform your list of Person into your desired object. Something like this:

`items.stream()
  .map(person -> new SimplePerson(person.name, person.dept) 
  .collect(Collectors.toList());`

where SimplePerson is a "reduced" version of your Person class. For example:

```
class SimplePerson{

  String name;
  String dept;
  public SimplePerson(String name,String dept){
    this.name=name;
    this.dept=dept;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Constructor need to have same name of class, isn't it?

Comment: Yep! Thank you for having noted it!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `PersonNameDeptDto` class:

```
public class PersonNameDeptDto {

  private String name;
  private String dept;

  public PersonNameDeptDto(Person p) {
    this.name = p.name;
    this.dept = p.dept;
  }
}
```

then populate your list:

```
List<PersonNameDeptDto> items=new ArrayList<>();
items.add(new PersonNameDeptDto(new Person(1,"hari","aa")));
```

As a side note, it's generally a good idea to include `id` in the dto unless you have another unique identifier.